# How do I make small screen frame to full screen by double click

Tags: android

I have a table layout with three objects, list view, Exo Player and Text View. I want to make the small screen full to match the parent height and width by a double click on the video or list view item. See attached screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Are you using androids view system or jetpack compose?

Comment: Daniel. I am using Android.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Funder7. Will post the code this afternoon.

Comment: @shariifi I know you use android. You can build UI's either with androids view system or the new jetpack compose. This is relevant for providing a good answer to your question.

Comment: I cannot paste the code here but basically what I need is when I click/double click the playing video on the small window to fill the whole screen. and then when I click the full screen video to resize back to small window shown in the picture.

Comment: I am using the latest Android Studio and exoplayer:2.15.1

 <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:use_controller="false"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/list_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />